# iframe is not display correclty in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using Webview to display iframe in android. Below is my java code

```
String html = "<p><blockquote><iframe height=\"740\" src=\"https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vSCZgt7yvY-9aB3RSvQqhYXE0EZ_Lp7AMTMmxlGfJP04iHBjX4A7dVVrc-b9OBX3kLWp_dLyUvNjhLa/pub?embedded=true\" width=\"100%\"> </iframe></blockquote></p>";
webview.loadData(html, "text/html",null);
```

below is my xml

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewPage"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="53dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when we run code its look like below screen
[image]

How its show margin or padding from left and right?
How can we resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you provide the whole xml code ?

Comment: Do you use javascript?

Answer (score 0):

u should make your WebView heght and width are match_parent

```js
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webViewPage"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="53dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `width=\"100%\"` to a value because It will not load correctly.

Just say `width=\"100px\"` by example and you will see that the borders are gone.